# CSV difference between foreach and parse methods

Tags: ruby, csv, foreach

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between parse and foreach in CSV?

Comment: [Documentation says what?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html) Please use the resources someone has taken the time to write. If the behavior [observed] is not *not* covered in the API (or a brief trip to a search engine), then that would make a better/suitable - and more refined - question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [Ruby Document here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html).

Generally speaking, `#parse` is used to parse a string while `#foreach` is for a file.